# Delete doc in react from firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I want to delete a doc in the firestore but I don't have the id of the firestore doc

how can I delete some doc if I know only the name?

this is how I export the DB: `export const db = getFirestore(app)`

I need to use a where operator but I don't find how

I try something like that

```
const onRemoveSong = async () => {
    await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'users',user?.email!, 'songs'),where('songId','=='song.id) )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass a query to Firestore and have it delete all documents that match those conditions. You will have to:

1. [Execute the query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query)
2. Loop over the results
3. Delete them one by one

In code that'd be something like this:

```
const q = query(
  collection(db, 'users',user?.email!, 'songs'), 
  where('songId','=='song.id)
);
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
for (const docSnapshot of querySnapshot.docs) {
  await deleteDoc(docSnapshot.ref);
});
```